# What is the best way to execute a slow function?

Tags: python, multithreading, scalability

I have a python function which takes about 1 min to execute. I need to run it for each user in my database. What is the best way to execute in least amount of time? (assuming I cannot decrease fn execution time). Should I spwan multiple threads for each user? (I have no control on user count).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your slow function is slow because it is CPU-intensive, spawning a thread for each user could be an hazard, if you have a big database you will probably have thousands of threads competing for resources. You can use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) to have a pool of workers:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(user):
    # do something

users = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Dave']
pool = Pool(processes=10)
results = pool.map(f, users)
```

Even if `users` turns out to be a list of a thousand names, you will always have a maximum of 10 processes running simultaneously. You should set the number of processes according to the number of cores your machine have.

Comment: What if my fn is not CPU intensive and waiting for multiple database queries?

Comment: @ravi local database queries? because that's cpu-intensive

Comment: @ravi even remote queries are cpu intensive (for the server) and you may lose efficiency when running lots of queries simultaneously. Play with the parameter `processes` to find a good number for your setup.